# move Employee ID from the selected rows of the table into a hidden List<string> column of the table

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I am trying to store the employeeIds from the selected row of the table into the model column EmployeeReinstateVM.selectedEmployeeId from the click event of 'btnUpdate', each id must be stored to  EmployeeReinstateVM.selectedEmployeeId. Currently the Ids are stored in to selectedEmployeeId hidden column as array string "23,24,25"  So I am trying to store each employee id of the selected rows into the EmployeeReinstateVM.selectedEmployeeId from javascript to send the model into controller post method with selected employeeIds. I am looking for the help from someone. Here is the code

Model Class

```
public class EmployeeReinstateVM
{
  public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
   public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
   public List<string> selectedEmployeeId { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<EmployeeModel> employees { get; set; }      
}
```

Views

```
<style>
.selectable-row.selected {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
</style>
@model EmployeeReinstateVM
foreach (var item in Model.employees)
{
  <tr class="selectable-row
  @(Model.selectedEmployeeId.Contains(item.EmployeeID.ToString()) ? "selected" :"")" 
  employee-id="@item.EmployeeID">
  <td>@item.EmployeeID</td>
  <td>@item.EmployeeName</td>
  </tr>
  
}
 <input hidden id="selectedEmployeeId" asp-for="selectedEmployeeId" name="selectedEmployeeId" value="">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="btnUpdate" name="btnActivate" value="update">
        Update
</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  var employeeIds = [];
  $(".selectable-row").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    var employeeId = $(this).attr('employee-id');

    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
      employeeIds.push(employeeId);
      //employeeIds.push($(this).attr('employee-id'));
    } else {
      employeeIds = employeeIds.filter(function(id) {
        return id !== employeeId;
      });
    }
  });
  $("#btnUpdate").click(function() {
    $("#selectedEmployeeId").val(employeeIds);
    console.log($("#selectedEmployeeId").val());
  });
})
```

Comment: In `$("#selectedEmployeeId").val(employeeIds);`you have send the employeeIds to the selectedEmployeeId. Could you explain it clear about what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be simpler - you need to store the result

```js
$(".selectable-row").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  $("#selectedEmployeeId")
    .val(
      $("tr[employee-id].selected")
       .map(function() { return $(this).attr("employee-id") })
       .get()
       .join(",")
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> store each employee id of the selected rows into the
> EmployeeReinstateVM.selectedEmployeeId from javascript to send the
> model into controller post method with selected employeeIds

Do you want to try the below code?

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            $("#selectedEmployeeId").val(employeeIds);
            console.log($("#selectedEmployeeId").val());
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Keepselected/ReinstateEmployee",
                data: { "selectedEmployeeId": employeeIds },
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                success: function (response) {                 
                   alert(response);
                }

            });
        });
```

result:
[image]

Comment: List<int>selectedEmployeeId is coming as null in controller

Comment: @Alevel  Check `data: { "selectedEmployeeId": employeeIds },`The name as List<int>selectedEmployeeId .